# Semi Automatic Classification

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm using QGIS and I want to do a classification of an LandSat8 image.

I already uploaded the image and did a pansharping on it. I clipped the image to my area of interest. Then i set the bend set to get the different band combinations.

The problem is, when I choose 4-3-2 qgis projects 5-4-3 ... I sorted the single bands when setting the band composite to the right order.

So there must be a failure which i don't get.

I am working with the Semi Automatic Classification plugin.

Comment: Maybey i forgott to say that i'm working with the Semi Automatic Classification plugin

Comment: Welcome. Please take the tour:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour.  And edit your question for clarity--are you receiving an error? If so, please include it. What behavior are you expecting vs. what you are seeing?

Comment: Hi, so to me it is still unclear what exactly your problem is here? Please be more specific, to get a qualified answer!

Comment: At first, thanks for your interest....

to MaryBeth: No, there is no Error. I expecting that qgis shows the right combinations. At landsat 8 the chanel for infrared light should be 5-4-3 and not 4-3-2, which is the chanel for naturell colours

@ADorsch: when i'm doing a pan sharping in qgis the result are the bands PAN_......_B2 to PAN_......._B7. When i choose the bands 4-3-2 it should project a composite with natruell colours

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.